# Vertically Scaling AWS-RDS instance type and deleting a reader without downtime?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm using AWS-RS(Aurora Postgress) and it's a cluster with one writer and about 4 readers. I want to scale up the instance type and also delete a reader with no downtime.

The writer and the readers have active connections which could break my application

How should i go about this to avoid downtime?

I tried bumping up the instance type in dev environment but there was a downtime